# How does the view redraw itself when I disable/enable a button?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, drawing, layoutsubviews

If I enable/disable a button…what method would get called on the view?

I’ve already placed a breakpoint on the `layoutSubviews` and don’t see it reaching there. Nor it reaches us to the viewController's `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. So I'm just curious to know how it works and what method it triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good question. I got curious about this myself, so I created a simple `UIButton` subclass and put breakpoints on a few overridden methods. Here are my findings:

1. Called `setEnabled:` on a `UIButton` subclass instance which I called `MyButton` in `viewDidLoad`
2. This triggered a call to `setNeedsDisplay` method. It was called internally by the `setEnabled` method of the `UIButton` class. As you can see from the stack trace in this screenshot:

   [image]
3. After `setNeedsDisplay`, the `setNeedsLayout` method was triggered. The stack trace was similar to the earlier call:

   [image]
4. After this the following methods were called in this order: `layoutSubviews`, `drawLayer:inContext:`, `drawRect:`

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) of the `UIView` class,

> When the actual content of your view changes, it is your responsibility to notify the system that your view needs to be redrawn. You do this by calling your view’s setNeedsDisplay() or setNeedsDisplay(_:) method of the view. These methods let the system know that it should update the view during the next drawing cycle. Because it waits until the next drawing cycle to update the view, you can call these methods on multiple views to update them at the same time.

And here is the documentation on the `enabled` boolean of `UIControl`:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the control is enabled.
>   Set the value of this property to YES to enable the control or NO to disable it. An enabled control is capable of responding to user interactions, whereas a disabled control ignores touch events and may draw itself differently. Setting this property to NO adds the UIControlStateDisabled flag to the control’s state bitmask; enabling the control again removes that flag.

They mention that a disabled control may re-draw itself differently. They also mention the control's `state` bitmask is updated. So, I believe, internally Apple's `UIButton` class calls the `setNeedsDisplay` method, which in-turn forces to re-draw itself. Based on the `(UIControlState) state` property, the button draws itself respectively. You can find more on UIButton drawing [here (look at Table 2 
Appearance attributes)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) and UIView drawing [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156).

But it probably won't trigger any events on the `UIViewController`'s view which has the button as a subview. Although, you could use KVO and observe the `enabled` property if you want to listen to changes to the property in your view controller or in the button's superview.

Comment: 1. So all of it happened at the `UIButton` layer? I actually wrote it on the button's parent view and the view's superview. I didn't override any method of the button itself. I guess that was all it.  2. And just to be sure. You're saying no method bubbled up to the button's super view?!

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that you were talking about the button's superview. I updated my answer accordingly. I don't think the button's superview gets any event callbacks.

Comment: Just to clarify Pranay: my hierachy was as such viewcontroller's view >> subview >> button (inside subview). I was looking into subview and viewcontroller's subview. You looked into the button itself.

Comment: Yes I looked into the button itself. I thought when you said "what method would get called on the view" in your question, that you were talking about the button's view itself. Anyway, in the hierarchy you mentioned, neither the superview of your button nor the view controller will get any callback for when a button is enabled or disabled. But if you want to get notified when the button is enabled or disabled, you can use KVO. Hope I answered your question?